# Execute vector multiplication in one variable of a tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have a tibble like this, which can be seen as a longitudinal dataset

```
df <- tibble( T = rep(1:5,each=3), dens = rnorm(15,0,1) )
```

From `df`, I wish to obtain a new `3-by-5` matrix, so that the first column is the value of `dens` for `T=1`; the second column is product of `dens[T=1] dens[T=2]` so on and so forth.

The expected output is

```
 new_df <- cbind(df$dens[1:3], dff$dens[1:3]*df$dens[4:6],df$dens[1:3]*df$dens[4:6]*df$dens[7:9],
                  df$dens[1:3]*df$dens[4:6]*df$dens[7:9]*df$dens[10:12],df$dens[1:3]*df$dens[4:6]*df$dens[7:9]*df$dens[10:12]*df$dens[13:15])
```

How this can be done in a tibble more efficiently?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to do a group by the `rowid` of 'T' column,  get the `cumprod` of 'dens' and reshape to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%       
   group_by(rn = rowid(T)) %>% 
   mutate(dens = cumprod(dens)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = T, values_from = dens) %>%
   select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#    `1`   `2`    `3`    `4`    `5`
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1  1.77 2.06   1.53   2.23  -4.41 
#2  1.96 0.414  0.522 -0.175  0.182
#3  1.57 3.18  -3.99  -4.59   6.64
```

-checking with OP's expected

```
cbind(df$dens[1:3], 
       df$dens[1:3]*df$dens[4:6],
       df$dens[1:3]*df$dens[4:6]*df$dens[7:9],
       df$dens[1:3]*df$dens[4:6]*df$dens[7:9]*df$dens[10:12],
       df$dens[1:3]*df$dens[4:6]*df$dens[7:9]*df$dens[10:12]*df$dens[13:15])
#         [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
#[1,] 1.773718 2.0604976  1.5309983  2.2307720 -4.4127195
#[2,] 1.961222 0.4142233  0.5222992 -0.1748975  0.1820611
#[3,] 1.571597 3.1822827 -3.9931628 -4.5932566  6.6440672
```

Comment: Thanks! In another scenario, if I only wish to keep the last column, do I only need to change ```pivot_wider(names_from=T,values_from=dens)``` to ```select(`5`)```?

Comment: @tobinz Yes, you can use `select` with backquotes for unusual column names

Comment: @tobinz Also, if you don't need all other columns, use `prod` instead of `cumprod`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a base R option using `Reduce` could help

```
> do.call(cbind, Reduce("*", with(df, split(dens, T)), accumulate = TRUE))
           [,1]        [,2]        [,3]       [,4]        [,5]
[1,] -1.2667876 -1.52064920 -2.25924893 2.55495272 -4.02049920
[2,] -0.2854711 -0.23282226  0.08117526 0.01885956 -0.01893413
[3,]  0.2698863 -0.07630793  0.06976650 0.05718294 -0.10454398
```